# asp.net mvc3: what should you test using unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to TDD. working on my first asp.net mvc3 project, plan to use unit test.

I saw some samples online teaching how to unit test your application.  testing routes, controller, custom model binders and repositories ...

what else should be tested with unit test?  I dont want to over test my applcation.

here's on sample i found online, i think its over test. correct me if I am wrong.

He wrote 5-6 tests to test his repository.  first, He creates 5 products.

then, test GetAllProducts, check count(), making sure its 5.
then, test GetById(int i), check count = 1, and name = "sdfsfd"
...
...

I dont see how this unit test gonna help. you make up your own list, you know what to expect.

please share your thoughts, as a bgeinner, how to unit test properly.

Answer (score 0):

Tests such as the one you described are useful because you can still use them when you test other areas of the system.

In your example, say your 'create' function adds a product with 3 fields, and later you adjust your model to have only 2 fields, the create step of the test will fail and you'll know that any 'create' code will need to be ammended.

More often than not, the tests should check the basic functions of each area so that you know if other areas break this at a later step. This kind of approach is key to regression testing and can save a lot of time in the long run.